# how to insert two or more label lists in the tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, multitasking, training-data

I am using the `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` to feed data in my model and train it in a similar way with the [MNIST example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers). The only difference is that I need to insert two numpy lists of labels instead of one. I tried passing them in a dictionary like this:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            x={"x": training_images},
            y={"labels1": training_labels1, "labels2": training_labels2},
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            num_epochs=None,
            shuffle=True)

my_cnn_model.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,steps=NUM_TRAINING_STEPS)
```

Then when I try to retrieve them in the model like so:

```
def build_cnn_model(features, labels, mode):
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'

I also tried to change the name of the variable "labels" to be "targets" according to [tensorflow inputs.numpy_input_fn documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn):

```
def build_cnn_model(features, targets, mode):
```

and I get this error:

> `ValueError: model_fn (<function build_cnn_model at 0x7f88df9c9d08>)
>   has following not expected args: ['targets']`

If you have any solution or suggestion to my problem, please let me know.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Antonios

Comment: Are you sure that `training_images`, `training_labels1` and `training_labels2` are numpy array and not python lists?

Comment: Yes I am sure.
I have managed to make it work with one numpy list of labels, the problem is when I use the second.

Comment: I also noticed that when I use the variable name "targets" inside the model the error occurs when I initialise the model:       

`my_cnn_model = tf.estimator.Estimator( model_fn=model.build_cnn_model, model_dir="./my_saved_model")`
which is before the estimator is used.